# What is the meaning of $\mathbb C[t]_t$ in the theory of local ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, localization

> I was reading local ring, multiplicative closed set, localization etc..where it was written that $(f(t)/t^m) \in \mathbb C[t]_t$ for some $m \in \mathbb N$ and $f(t)\in \mathbb C[t].$ Here what is the meaning of $\mathbb C[t]_t$ ?

Please someone help..

Thank you..

Comment: It's the localization of $\Bbb C[t]$ at $(t)$ i.e the set of rational functions on the form $g(t)/t^m$ for $m \in \Bbb Z$ with $g(t) \in \Bbb C[t]$.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet I'd say that it is the localization at $t$, that is, at the multiplicative set $\{1,t,t^2,\dots\}$.

Comment: @user26857 : yes you are right, I was thinking to the localization at a prime ideal but of course it's a different ring...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The four typical meanings I would see that notation given are:

- The *completion* of $\mathbb{C}[t]$ at the prime ideal $(t)$ — that is, the power series ring $\mathbb{C}[[t]]$.
- The *local ring* of $\mathbb{C}[t]$ at the prime ideal $(t)$ — that is, the ring of all rational functions whose denominator is not divisible by $t$.
- The ring obtained by inverting $t$ — that is, $\mathbb{C}[t, t^{-1}]$. It is the ring of all polynomials in $t$ and $t^{-1}$, or equivalently the ring of all rational functions whose denominator is a power of $t$.
- The quotient ring $\mathbb{C}[t] / (t)$.

The last is, I think, by far the least common. The third is the next least common  — but given the context you saw it in, it's the only one that makes sense.

Since you are talking about the basics, note:

- The second bullet above is obtained by inverting the multiplicatively closed subset of all polynomials that aren't in the ideal $(t)$
- The third bullet above is obtained by inverting the multiplicatively closed set generated by $t$ — that is, the set of powers of $t$.

Comment: From "*it was written that $(f(t)/t^m) \in \mathbb C[t]_t$ for some $m \in \mathbb N$ and $f(t)\in \mathbb C[t].$*" the only possible interpretation is the third.